# onChange will trigger without a spreadsheet change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting, eventtrigger

This is a google trigger behavior question. (I think).
Wondering if this is normal.

I have (several) sheets that have a 'on-change' trigger for a script.
I have noticed that they somehow get triggered without changes to the sheet, and when the sheet is closed.
With just a onChange trigger that increases a value in a cell when it triggers, the cell value increases during the day, triggering at least every 15 minutes, sometimes every minute.

I have tried stripping the sheets down, getting rid of all IMPORTDATA and other external data references, so the sheet has nothing in it.
Very basic.

Looking at the Developer Hub - My executions, I see it showing these executions. Since there are a few similar copies of the same basic sheet, some will not trigger a on-change for hours then start rapidly showing triggers while another sheet seems to behave itself, for a while.

Like I said, there is nothing much on the sheet, just a few formulas that reference cells on the same sheet but that's it.

Comment: You said that `I have (several) sheets that have a 'on-change' trigger for a script.` How did you assign that trigger to specific sheets?  and thus exclude other sheets.

Comment: 5 separate sheets, meaning new spreadsheets not tabs-pages within the same sheet.

Comment: What type of change are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that they return an event object. But I only get "OTHER" as the changeSource.

Comment: I wonder if anyone knows what OTHER means.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a test on one of my spreadsheets to see if I can get the same result:

```
function catchChanges(e) {
  var ts=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss");
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('ssid');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Change Log');
  sh.appendRow([ts,e.changeType,e.triggerUid,e.user,e.authMode]);
}
```

Comment: @Robert C I checked the Change Log and I haven't received any triggers.

Comment: my intention was to "turn-off" these 5 sheets time triggers when not in use. Although fairly simple, they pull a lot of data and I was running into use limit issues.   the really unusual thing is some of the sheets will not trigger a onChange for days, and then suddenly they trigger a onChange every half hour, or every 10 minutes. next day its a different sheet. They have all had the IMPORTDATA functionality removed to troubleshoot.

Comment: It might be useful for you to log all triggers to the same log with a timestamp to see if there is any correlation between them.

Comment: @Cooper Ads script writes to a spreadsheet but doesn't trigger onChange event. Can I somehow trigger it without a manual action?

Comment: I worked on an another question recently and I found that importRange can trigger an onChange of type "OTHER"  but unfortunately the sheet that is returned with `e.source.getActiveSheet()` is always `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];` so you get a trigger but you can't tell where it came from